# iOS Notifications and location services permissions displaying multiple times at launch

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

In iOS 10+, when I launch my app I get both the request notifications and location services firing twice. The first one briefly appears and disappears immediately without allowing me to do any actions, then I got the second popup with a normal behaviour waiting for "allow" or "deny" from the user.

Here is a [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOshU.gif) of the issue.

Here is the notifications method in my AppDelegate :

```
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    if #available(iOS 10, *) { // iOS 10 support
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }else if #available(iOS 9, *) { // iOS 9 support
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    AppEventsLogger.activate(application)

}
```

Here is the locations services method in my AppDelegate:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //
    self.setupLocationService()


 func setupLocationService(){
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways{
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }else if status == .notDetermined{
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }else{
        print("Location service disabled")
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not complete. Can you share complete code for didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is happening due to you asking for two permission request. So you need to change you code as following.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: { (authorised, error) in
    self.setupLocationService()
})
```

Just update you code like this. This will first ask you notification authorisation request. Based on user interaction with popup, thereafter ask for you location permission request.

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Write notification code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    setupLocationService()

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func setupLocationService(){
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways{
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }else if status == .notDetermined{
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }else{
        print("Location service disabled")


    }
    }

}
```